# Adding Layer to existing Feature Layer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online

I have an existing hosted Feature Layer and I need to add a few layers to it.

How would I do that in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: From what I can gather, it appears that a desktop application is required to make changes to a hosted Feature Layer. Is this correct? If not, how would I add, from ArcGIS Online, a new layer?

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications or additional information.  What precisely have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need an exact clone of the feature layer that you currently have hosted on ArcGIS Online, you can download the feature layer in your desired format from the Feature Layer's admin page in ArcGIS Online and use either process described below to re-publish the data to ArcGIS Online.

You can add all of the desired layers into a new MXD, sign in to ArcGIS Online from the File menu. From there go to File > Share As > Service. Use the overwrite option and select the feature layer you wish to add layer items to. After this, you will have a single Feature Layer with both the original and new layer items contained within it.

Alternatively, if you do not have access to ArcGIS Desktop, you can place each of the shapefiles you want to upload into a single zip file, and upload by doing the following. Go to my content > add item > from my computer, and select the zip file that contains the shapefiles you wish to upload.